# Tooltip hides on Overflow scroll/auto container

Tags: html, css, angular, tooltip, vmware-clarity

I'm using Angular - Clarity with cards and tooltip..

Please see the URL -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-wio9hp

Here the tooltip is hidden inside the card...I need only tooltip to be displayed or don't cut-off over the card, inside contents need to be oveflow scroll/auto..

In fact I have searched for many answers but doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1):

.tooltip-content has `position: relative`, therefor it will always display inside the card.

An alternative solution can be to display the tooltip based on mouse position.

Make tooltip-content `position: fixed` to display it outside the box.

```css
.tooltip-content {
  position: fixed!important;
}
```

It will need some custom code to have the tooltip positioned on the right spot. But you could do that based on the mouse position. See this post: [Angular 4 Observables mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973483/angular-4-observables-mouse-coordinates)

Bind the element style top and left to the tooltip element and the tooltip will follow your mouse: `<span class="tooltip-content" [style.top]="mouseY + 'px'" [style.left]="mouseX + 'px'">` Of course the rest of the elements will need some more styling to have it displayed neatly.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-aogelj in this example the first  tag will show what I mean.

You can also get the coordinates of the `<a>` element you are currently hovering over. And display the tooltip with `position: fixed` and `top: elementY px` `left: elementX px`. Ways to get the DOM element are described here: [How to get dom element in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944725/how-to-get-dom-element-in-angular-2)